# Why doesn't my version of the Fibonacci function work?

Tags: python

The following Fibonacci function doesn't work:

```
def fib():
    n = int(input("Nth term "))
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))

    print(fib())
```

But this exponent function does

```
def hj():
    num1 = int(input("Enter your number: "))
    num2 = int(input("enter another number: "))
    return num1**num2

print(hj())
```

What could be the reason as to why a of the same form works for one application but doesn't for the other?

Comment: Your indentations are wrong. `print(fib())` should be outside the function

Comment: You shouldn't be taking input inside of a recursive function like that. Instead, take input outside of the function and pass it as an argument. The same goes for your exponent function. Even though it works, it is better practice to accept user input outside of the function and pass it into the function via arguments.

Comment: apart from all that has already been said I add that if you get all else you will get a TypeError error since in the last instruction you call fib parameter while the declaration does not accept them.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for user input every time `fib()` gets called. Lift it out of the function.

Also `fib()` has no parameters, but you try to call `fib(n-1)`

Refactor to:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))

n = int(input("Nth term "))
print(fib(n))
```

Comment: Thanks I got it, recursion is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `fib()` has no parameters, but you are calling you function like this which is wrong in that case `fib(n-1)`
and You should not taking user input inside a recursive function:

```
def fib(n):        
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
n = int(input("Nth term "))
print(fib(n))
```